# NullInjectorError: No provider for xxx With Injector

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have the following service:

```
@Injectable()
export class StudentService {

  constructor() { }

  getDataFormStudentService() {
    return "Hi, I'm Mix";
  }
}
```

Now that, I want to use the service above in `app.components.ts` :

```
  title = '';
  public studentService: StudentService;

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector) {
    this.studentService = this.injector.get(StudentService);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.title = this.studentService.getDataFormStudentService();
  }
```

When I run my project I get the following error :

> ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[StudentService ->
> StudentService -> StudentService]:    NullInjectorError: No provider
> for StudentService!

Comment: You have to provide the service. Try `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})` in your service class decorator.

Comment: @R. Richards - thanks , It's your right, How we can use  Injector here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide your service in your module where you got the component

Comment: I do not want to add my service in providers of the module ,I want to use Injector

Answer (score 0):

You can use providers property under the @Component annotation. It will inject only to your component, and it will create a new instance of the service all the time when your component has been loaded.

```js
@Component({
  /* . . . */
  providers: [StudentService]
})
```

Comment: I do not want to add my service in providers of the Component ,I want to use Injector

Comment: You should provider your service somewhere , before you would like to get it with injector.

`this.injector.get(...)` will works if you have provided the service in somewhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error using Angular 9 and I solved by:

1. By adding the @Injectable() annotation to the component that was to be used/referenced from another component, as: @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class BankComponent {}
2. By adding the injectable-marked component as a parameter to the constructor of my other component as: constructor(private bankComponent: BankComponent) { }

I hope that this will work for you too.